# TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
       json= new Gson().toJson(name);
```

where name is of type string.

I am getting error saying  "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj "

error is in  the given part of java script

```
 return type === "array" || type !== "function" &&
     ( length === 0 ||
     typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj );
```

I have also tried

```
   response=JSON.parse(response);
```

which is not working.

Comment: what is `responseJson`

Comment: response object which i am getting from servlet

Comment: element of type object

Comment: As the error suggests, `obj` doesn't seem to be a valid operand for `in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by link [In operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) you can see that

> The in operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object.

in your code `( length - 1 ) in obj` you try checking that property `(length - 1)` that numeric in your obj

I think `obj` is a `string`, so it has the `length` property, but does not have numeric properties, so you must catch this case

Comment: that is common java script  for many servlets , i cant change that that for just numeric value

Comment: so can you provide what is obj value?

Comment: So? If you have `var obj = {5: 'foo'};` then `5 in obj` would return `true`. The error suggests that `obj` is not a valid operand for `in`.

Comment: @FelixKling your comment to me or OP? :-)

Comment: @FelixKling, ok :-) where in my answer contradicts your comment?

Comment: It sounded like you said `in` couldn't be used with numeric properties.

Comment: @FelixKling, oh, no, i mean that `obj` does not have numeric properties and so raise error

Comment: That wouldn't throw an error though. `1 in {}` returns `false`. But you are right, if `obj` is not an object but e.g. a string, then it throws an error.

Comment: obj value are simple strings like "time" or "task" etc

Comment: in all other cases i am using string list , in this particular case it is string . to generalize the method i am converting everything in to json object . . when i convert the string to json object , i am getting this error

Comment: @user2814799: As said, `in` doesn't work with strings. Run `0 in 'foo'` in the console and you will see.

Comment: @user2814799: Also,  [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @user2814799 try using string list with one element instead of string

Answer (score 1):

I closed the code "( length - 1 ) in obj" between parentheses.

```
return type === "array" || type !== "function" &&
     ( length === 0 ||
     typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && (( length - 1 ) in obj) );
```

That's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the object was not empty but I needed to add double quotes on the object's key , example :

```
obj = {params : "paramsInputPreData"}
```

The Above will produce an error  but the one below was okay :

```
obj = {"params" : "paramsInputPreData"}
```

so for me the key needed to be quoted as "params"

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

When you have this error, you need to check the type of your variables, etc., you can always do something like this:

```
if (typeof x == 'string' || typeof x == 'number') { ... }
```